# Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am new in open source. Whenever I am importing a project from github to android studio, then gradle is not syncing and showing  :
**Project WaterReminder is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_281
Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
while using Android Studio.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDbCX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.